# separating stdout and sterr in cron jobs

Tags: logging, cron

***I'm not sure if this belongs here on on serverfault as it seems somewhat borderline. If serverfault would be better, please shift it over and apologies for the trouble.

I have a task running on cron and I want the stderr and std out to be redirected to a file and just the stderr to be directed to a file. (note: the script is PHP)

I've tried things like

```
<script> 1>> a.log 2>> | tee -a a.log | /bin mail -sE
```

and

```
<script> | a.log  2>> /bin/mail -sE
```

but I can't seen to get it just right. Either stdout winds up in the mail or I get double entries in the log file etc.

I also tried

```
<script> >> test.log  2> tee test.log | /bin/mail -s
```

but the email was always blank even when I introduced an error. A message was displayed to stdout immediately upon start  execution (the script takes about 40 seconds to complete): "Null message body; hope that's ok"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that works

```
<script> 1 3>> <log> 2>&1 1>&3 | tee -a <log> | /bin/mail
```